# I need some rails migration help for adding/removing foreign_key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

On my local machine with I run `rake db:migrate` there are a couple add_foreign_key constraints removed from the db/schema.rb file but when I run the same command on my dev server rails adds them back in. I've checked the mysql & rails versions and they are the same. Can someone guide/tell me what is going on here?

local machine:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

$ rails --version
Rails 4.2.6

$ gem list --local mysql2
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
mysql2 (0.4.4)
```

dev server:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

$ rails --version
Rails 4.2.6

$ gem list --local mysql2
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
mysql2 (0.4.4)
```

Comment: Do you remove just from the schema file? If yes, then this won't work. You need to create a new migration file in which you'll remove foreign key constraints.

Comment: I don't remove anything. Rails does it whey I run the command.

Comment: Okay. First of all i don't think the problem is with rails or mysql version. Taking a wild guess, are you collaborating with someone who might be pushing the schema file having add_foreign_key constraints?

Comment: `db/schema.rb` is a representation of the database as it currently exists when `schema.rb` is generated, it doesn't necessarily depend on what's in your migrations, it depends on how the database is structured. So look at your production database using the `mysql` CLI tool and see if the FKs are there, if they're not then add them and regenerate `schema.rb`. Of course, you should test this with an exact copy of your production database first and be prepared for problems.

Comment: Is it possible to share the migration code? Can you check the config files for both dev server and the local?

Comment: "Okay. First of all i don't think the problem is with rails or mysql version. Taking a wild guess, are you collaborating with someone who might be pushing the schema file having add_foreign_key constraints?" No i'm the only dev on the project right now.

Comment: @mu is too short this was the problem. My local db and dev db where out of sync. I'm not sure what I did because I 'thought' I ran a mysqldump with the same sql file on both db's. Will you answer the question and I'll accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand that `db/schema.rb` represents ActiveRecord's understanding of your database the last time the `db:schema:dump` Rake task was run. The database's structure (as seen in `db/schema.rb`) may or may not exactly match what you see in your `db/migrate` directory: migrations could have been added and removed, database options changed, aliens, things could have been manually changed (i.e. outside migrations), ...

Looks like FKs were added in your development database but not your production database or they were removed from production (or ignored) so your databases are out of sync. Check your production database using the `mysql` CLI tool and see if the FKs are there; if they're not then synchronized your databases by hand or with a production-only migration. You'll probably want to do this on an exact copy of your production database first so that you can make sure that all the FKs are valid before unleashing chaos on a production system.

---

Similar things apply to `db/structure.sql` if you use the "raw SQL" format for managing your schema.